# The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (131.103.20.168)' can't be established

Tags: bitbucket, cloud9-ide

In Cloud9 I do:

```
$ git push -u origin --all

The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (131.103.20.168)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

I added the `ssh-key` from cloud9 to Bitbucket. Shouldn't that be enough to have Bitbucket authenticated by Cloud9?

Comment: Warning: [starting June 2023, the Bitbucket RSA host key will change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76266042/6309).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. When you'll first connecting to bitbucket, ssh client on your machine will store RSA fingerprint in file called `known_hosts`. Then before each connection server fingerprint will be validated with stored one (to avoid man-in-the-middle attack).

So - you need to accept this fingerprint only once (if you're diligent you should compare it with [fingerprint provided by bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-ssh-protocol-with-bitbucket-cloud-221449711.html)).

Comment: Thanks. Ha ha, not paranoid ;-) Just wanted to fully understand. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

### If your key is added, you might be missing this important step...

When we get the prompt `Are you sure you want to continue connecting(yes/no)?` then we should type `yes` before hitting the `return/Enter` key.

Good Luck.